# Async not awaiting the function to complete before executing next line

Tags: node.js, express, node-mssql

I'm using [node-mssql](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#bulk-table-options-callback/). The line `return res.send(result)` is executed before `var result = await client(3)`, this should not be the case because I have `await` on `var result = await client(3)`.

After debugging I came to a point where the following code is not waiting for the function to finish.

```
request.bulk(table, (err, result) => {
    if(err){
        return err
    }
    if(result){
        return result
    }
})
```

Here's the rest of the sample code.

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    var result = await client(3)
    return res.send(result)
})

const client = async (client_id) => {
    ...
    const table = new sql.Table('table_name')
    table.create = true
    table.columns.add('a', sql.Int, {nullable: true, primary: true})
    table.columns.add('b', sql.VarChar(50), {nullable: false})
    table.rows.add(777, 'test')

    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.bulk(table, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return err
        }
        if(result){
            return result
        }
    })
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap `request.bulk` with a Promise. It is also asynchronous operation, but it goes with a callback function instead of returning promise. So wrap it with promise and await it. Or find an example of how this method is called to return a promise. I see they have that option in the doc but not seeing example: https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#bulk-table-options-callback

Comment: Probably `await request.bulk(table);` will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.bulk()` is not using promises so it's not connected at all to what `client()` returns.  You can fix that by manually promisifying it:

```
const client = async (client_id) => {
    ...
    const table = new sql.Table('table_name')
    table.create = true
    table.columns.add('a', sql.Int, {nullable: true, primary: true})
    table.columns.add('b', sql.VarChar(50), {nullable: false})
    table.rows.add(777, 'test')

    const request = new sql.Request()
    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.bulk(table, (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
    ...
    return result;
}
```

And, keep in mind that `await` only does something useful when you await a promise that resolves only when you have completed the work.  But, your `client()` function returns a promise by virtue of being `async` and that promise isn't connected at all to when `request.bulk()` finishes.  So, to fix that, the code above created a promise that is tied to when `request.bulk()` finishes and uses `await` with it.  That causes the promise that parent `async` function returns to then be tied to when the actual work is done.

FYI, if your database driver has native promise support built-in, then you can use that directly without having to promisify it yourself.